# SQL - Use object property as parameter for function

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I am struggling to formulate the right sql-query to access the property of an object stored in one of my columns and use it as an input for a function:

- I have a table 'search'
- in 'search' one column is named 'coord' and stores POINT-Objects
- I defined a function 'test' which gets a double-input parameter and just returns the input parameter as double

I want to make a query such as

```
SELECT test('coord.X') as res FROM `search` ORDER BY res
```

Expected result: The coord.X values listed in a columns named 'res' ordered from lowest to highest.

What I get is '0' for every entry (the coord X/Y values are of course set to arbitrary values).

If I leave the coord.X without the "'" around it the query fails with an error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'coord.X' in 'field list'
```

I searched a lot but I couldnt find any pages telling me how to access properties of sql-objects. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Neither POINT or Object are SQL native data types. What data type is used to coord?

Comment: Yes that is true. Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Its this type I am refering to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-class-point.html

Comment: What is some example data in coord? Also, the site you have provided a link to has an example of `select x(@p), y(@p)` did you try `x(coord)`?

Comment: x(coord) is perfectly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Can you post that as the answere so I can upvote it? I am still interested on the facts behind it though... Isn't "POINT" an object? Is it the standard-way to access properties in (my)SQL by calling the property followed by the object wrapped in brackets? This seems a bit odd...

Comment: Please note, @user3440145, in order to notify someone of your comment include '@' + username in the comment. You received the comment notifications from everyone else because the comments were on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your sample query without the test function.

```
SELECT coord.X as res FROM `search` ORDER BY res
```

Sql views `coord.X` as a column name and looks for that column in `search`. Since X is a property of coord, rather than part of the column name, this is what was causing your error.

Using

```
SELECT test(X(coord)) as res FROM `search` ORDER BY res
```

Should yield the correct results. Just as the syntax to call your test function is `test()`, the syntax to call the X function (defined in spacial extensions) is `X()`. However, this function will not work on columns that are not explicitly declared as a Point type because sql will not know how to parse the value and return the specified information.

Essentially, `X()` is similar to the many other mysql functions, such as `ISNULL()` or `SUM()`. Just as `SUM()` expects int data types as input, `X()` expects Point data types.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the query be:

SELECT coord as res FROM `search` ORDER BY res

Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answere.
'coord' refers to the column that stores geospatial objects of type POINT. That has (according to this site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-class-point.html) a X-Property. And that property I want to access.